# Sublime Text 3 - stop side menu folders jumping to highlight current file

Tags: sublimetext3

Is it possible to set Sublime Text to stop the side menu jumping to the currently active/editing file? I often want to refer to other file names and locations when typing and having the side menu leap away is driving me loopy.

I have the "SideBarEnhancements" and "Advanced New File" packages installed.

Comment: Not sure if I understand what you want. Do you want sublime to not [highlight selected file](http://s16.postimg.org/wk6ephjrl/files.png)?

Comment: Correct I want sublime to NOT highlight the active page in the side menu. I don't mind it being graphically highlighted but I don't want the menu to jump down to that location.

Comment: I can't reproduce that jumping/scrolling you describe. When does it occurs?

Comment: I am working on various magento projects so the folder and file lists are very long.  If I have a file open from one of the top folders in the structure and then a file open in a folder lower down (say with lots of the folders in between open) then changing the focus from one file to another makes the file list jump around.  On short lists where the files are both visible then nothing really happens.

Comment: This is choppy and jumps rather than scrolls but here it is in action: [link](http://www.indigojazz.co.uk/sublime-scroll.wmv)

Comment: I have set a two columns layout like yours, opened many folders in order to have a longer list, opened a top and a lower down file, and  I have installed SideBarEnhancements and AdvancedNewFile. But I still can't reproduce that problem. For me it works as you want. I'm using sublime text 3 build3083 on Linux Mint.

Comment: Thajnks for taking the time to try that sergioFC.  I am running it on Windows.  How odd.

Comment: For reference I am also using build 3083